# When input is focus or filled in then show div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the condition, when input is focus or filled in then show a div on each input element.

On focus it is working fine, but not able to get this work on filled input.

```js
$('.field').focus(function() {
  $('.placeholder-text').hide();
  var i = 0;

  $('.field').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":focus") || $(this).val() > 0) {
      $($('.placeholder-text')[i]).show();
    }
    i++;
  })

  $(document).bind('focusin.placeholder-text click.placeholder-text', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('.placeholder-text, .field').length) return;
    $(document).unbind('.placeholder-text');
    $('.placeholder-text').fadeOut('medium');
  });
});
$('.placeholder-text').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" class="field" name="name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
<div class="placeholder-text" for="name">First Name</div>

<input id="lname" class="field" type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
<span class="placeholder-text" for="lname">Last Name</span>
```

Comment: You probably want to check the _length_ of the value for being > 0, not the actual value itself. (Or compare it to an empty string instead.)

Comment: I do not quite get the problem. If you want to fill the input you will have to focus it anyway, or am I missing something? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @TA I think Zain wants to show a placeholder when there is no text or the field is focussed since the placeholder IN the field disappears

Comment: @mplungjan I get it, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use .on instead of .bind, but do not bind on each and every focus like you are now
2. bind on focus, blur and on input
3. there is no "for" except for labels

---

```js
$(".field").on("input", function() {
  $(this).next().toggle(this.value != "");
});
$(".field").on("blur", function() {
  if (this.value == "") $(this).next().fadeOut('medium');
})
$(".field").on("focus", function() {
  $(this).next().fadeIn('medium');
})
```

```css
.placeholder-text { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" class="field" name="name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" /><span class="placeholder-text">First Name</span><br/>

<input id="lname" class="field" type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" /><span class="placeholder-text">Last Name</span>
```

Comment: i'm using your code, i don't know why it is not working but here is working fine :(

Comment: Working now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

While this is, of course, possible with JavaScript – and any of its libraries – it's also possible using pure CSS, if you're able to add the `required` attribute to the `<input>` elements, and then styling the visibility of the adjacent `.placeholder-text` element with the `:valid` psuedo-class:

```
input:focus+.placeholder-text,
input:valid+.placeholder-text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Note that I've used a transition of the element's `opacity` to adjust the visibility of the `.placeholder-text` elements to avoid the jarring effect of the sudden appearance/disappearance inherent in using `display: none`/`display: initial` (or `display: block`).

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

input+.placeholder-text {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
}

input:focus+.placeholder-text,
input:valid+.placeholder-text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input id="name" class="field" name="name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" required />
<div class="placeholder-text" for="name">First Name</div>

<input id="lname" class="field" type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required />
<span class="placeholder-text" for="lname">Last Name</span>
```

It's also possible – with CSS – using the `:placeholder-shown` pseudo-class; though this depends on the browser compatibility you require (Internet Explorer, Edge and Opera Mini have no support as I write); the `:placeholder-shown` pseudo-class matches an `<input>` element if it's placeholder value is currently visible:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

input + .placeholder-text {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
}

input:not(:placeholder-shown) + .placeholder-text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input id="name" class="field" name="name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
<div class="placeholder-text" for="name">First Name</div>

<input id="lname" class="field" type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
<span class="placeholder-text" for="lname">Last Name</span>
```

Or, to simplify the CSS selector and avoid the use of the `:not()` negation operator:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

input:placeholder-shown+.placeholder-text {
  opacity: 0;
}

input+.placeholder-text {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
}
```

```html
<input id="name" class="field" name="name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" required />
<div class="placeholder-text" for="name">First Name</div>

<input id="lname" class="field" type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required />
<span class="placeholder-text" for="lname">Last Name</span>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).
  - [`:placeholder-shown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown)<sup>["Can I Use" compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder)</sup>.
  - [`:valid` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid).
- HTML:

  - [HTML attributes (for the `required` attribute)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes).

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to your HTML structure and I have given some CSS too. I have optimized the jQuery code and it is according to your requirements. Please have a look.

```js
$(".first-name #name, .last-name #lname").on("focus", function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".placeholder-text").show();
});
$(".first-name #name, .last-name #lname").blur("focus", function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".placeholder-text").hide();
  if ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == null) {
    $(this).parent().find(".placeholder-text").show();
  }
});
```

```css
.placeholder-text {
  display: none;
}

.flex-box {
  display: flex;
}

.first-name,
.last-name {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-box">
  <div class="first-name">
    <input id="name" class="field" name="name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
    <div class="placeholder-text" for="name">First Name</div>
  </div>
  <div class="last-name">
    <input id="lname" class="field" type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <span class="placeholder-text" for="lname">Last Name</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this was helpful.